# Powershell script calendar size issue

Tags: powershell, calendar, exchange-server

Trying to run the following script to get calendar size in Exchange 2016:

```
# Get-MailboxFolderSize.ps1 edit as required for folder you need stats on.
#$mailboxes = @(Get-Mailbox -ResultSize Unlimited)
$mailboxes = @(Get-MailboxServer | where-object {$_.AdminDisplayVersion.Major -eq 15} | Get-Mailbox -ResultSize Unlimited)
#$mailboxes = @(Get-MailboxServer | where-object {$_.AdminDisplayVersion.Major -eq 15} | Get-Mailbox)
#$mailboxes = @(Get-Mailbox hatfiemh)
$report = @()

foreach ($mailbox in $mailboxes)
{
    $inboxstats = Get-MailboxFolderStatistics $mailbox -FolderScope Calendar | Where {$_.FolderPath -eq "/Calendar"}
    $mbObj = New-Object PSObject
    $mbObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Display Name" -Value $mailbox.DisplayName
    $mbObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Calendar Size (gb)" -Value $inboxstats.FolderandSubFolderSize.ToGB()
    $mbObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Calendar Items" -Value $inboxstats.ItemsinFolderandSubfolders
    $report += $mbObj
}

$report
```

I get the following error message:

> You cannot call a method on a Null-valued expression.
>
> at c:\Get-MailboxFolderSize.psi:13 char:5
>
> $mbObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "inbox Size

Comment: Looks like you didn't copy/paste very well, since your errors references a line that has `"inbox Size <M` in it, but none of your example code has that line. It looks like some of your mailboxes do not have a calendar, and `$inboxstats` is ending up null instead of whatever kind of object `Get-MailboxFolderStatistics` outputs.

Comment: You are right: this should be the full line: $mbObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Calendar Size (MB)" -Value $inboxstats.FolderandSubFolderSize.ToMB()